# Creating an HOC for React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to create an HOC component for a presentational component and having a bit of trouble with the syntax.

Let's say my presentational component is called `BlogViewerBase` and let's call the HOC component `BlogViewerHoc`. I want the following:

1. I want to include some handler functions in my HOC component
2. I want the HOC component to connect to my Redux store, get state and pass it to the base component

Does this code look right?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

// Actions
import * as myActions from '../actions/myActions';

// Base component
import BlowViewerBase from '../components/blogViewerBase';

function hocBlogViewer(BlogViewerBase) {

    return class BlogViewerHoc extends React.Component {

       handlerFunction1() {

          // Some logic here
       }

       handlerFunction2() {

          // Some logic here
       }

       render() {

           return <BlogViewerBase {...this.props} />
       }
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

   return {

      var1: state.module.variable1,
      var2: state.module.variable2
   };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(myActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BlogViewerHoc(BlogViewerBase));
```

Where I'm struggling is that the examples of HOC components I've come across look more like  functions and I think I'm forming mine more like a component so not sure if I'm connecting to the store the right way. Not sure if the `mapPropsToState`, `mapDispatchToState` and the handler functions are in the right places.

Comment: Didnt you forget to pass props to wrapped component?`<BlogViewerBase handlerFunction1={this.handlerFunction1} handlerFunction2={this.handlerFunction2} {...this.props} />`.I cant help you because i know little about redux.

Comment: Yes, the handler functions will be passed too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define your HOC and then pass your presentational component to it. Also, you can bind an action creator to your props in mapDispatchToProps. Something like:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { myActionCreator } from 'yourPathToYourActions';

// Actions
import * as myActions from '../actions/myActions';

// Base component
import BlowViewerBase from '../components/blogViewerBase';

function hocBlogViewer(WrappedComponent) {

    return class extends React.Component {

       handlerFunction1() {

          // Some logic here
       }

       handlerFunction2() {

          // Some logic here
       }

       componentDidMount() {
         // I can dispatch this action now
         this.props.myActionInProps();
       }

       render() {

           return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
       }
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

   return {

      var1: state.module.variable1,
      var2: state.module.variable2
   };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

    return {
        myActionInProps: dispatch(myActionCreator())
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(hocBlogViewer(BlowViewerBase));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be OK to me :)

Maybe for simplicity of reading I would do the following adjustments (but this is just my opinion):

```
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)

...

export default function hocBlogViewer(BlogViewerBase) {

  return connector(
    class BlogViewerHoc extends React.Component {
...
```